# Query optimization order by

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting, indexing

I have two tables

1. LangArticles | columns: id (INT) ,de (VARCHAR),en (VARCHAR),count_links(INT)
2. WikiLinks    | columns: article_id,link_id,nr_in_article (all integer)

The name of an article is in the columns de (German) and en (English).
The id in the LangArticles table is the same as the ids article_id and link_id.

I want now to get all article names which links to another article. So I want all articles which links to 'abc'. 'abc' has the id = '1'

So my normal query (without an order by) looks like:

```
 select distinct(LA.de),W.nr_in_article,LA.count_links from
 LangArticles as LA inner join WikiLinks as W on W.article_id = LA.id
 where W.link_id in ("1")
```

This maybe took 0.001 seconds and give me 100000 results. Actually I want the best 5 hits.
Best means in this case the most relevant ones. I want to sort it like this:
The articles which links to 'abc' at the beginning of an article (nr_in_article) and which has a lot of links itself (count_links) should have a high ranking.

I am using an

```
order by (1-(W.nr_in_article/LA.count_links)) desc
```

for this.

The problem is that I am not sure how to optimize this order by.

The Explain in mysql says that he has to use a temporary file and filesort and can't use the index on the order by keys. For testing I tried an "easy" order by W.nr_in_article so an normal order with one key.

For your information my indices are:

in LangArticles: id (primary),de (unique),en (unique), count_links(index)

in WikiLinks: article_id(index),link_id(index),nr_in_article(index)

But I tried this two multiindices link_id,nr_in_article & article_id,nr_in_article as well.

And the query with order by tooks approximately 5.5 seconds. :(

I think I know why MySql has to use a temporary file and filesort here because all 100,000 entries has to be found with one index (link_id) and afterwards it has to be sorted and in a temporary file it can't use an index.

But is there any way to make this faster? 
Actually I only want the best 5 hits so there is no need to sort everything. I am not sure if sth. like the bad sort (bubble sort) would be faster for this than Quicksort which sorts the hole temporary table.

Comment: So since you only need the top five, you did put 'LIMIT 5' at the end of the query, right? Not sure mysql will be any faster with it, but you should at least try.

Comment: Btw, I never saw a distinct on one column like in distinct(LA.de)? How does this behave!? Like a group by!?

Comment: I tried to put a limit 5 but I saw it's not faster so I think that MySql uses a complete sort (QuickSort)

Comment: Ok, that's what I had expected. It's very likely not quicksort though, but mergesort (just FYI, it's not really relevant in regards to the issue at hand).

Answer (score 0):

Since you only need the top 5 I think you could split it into two queries that should lead less results.

First like Sam pointed out,

```
order by (W.nr_in_article/LA.count_links) asc
```

should be equivalent to your

```
order by (1-(W.nr_in_article/LA.count_links)) desc
```

unless I'm overlooking some corner case here.

Furthermore, anything where

```
W.nr_in_article > LA.count_links
```

will be in the TOP 5 unless that result is empty, so I would try the query

```
 select distinct(LA.de),W.nr_in_article,LA.count_links
 from LangArticles as LA 
 inner join WikiLinks_2 as W on W.article_id = LA.id
 and W.nr_in_article > LA.count_links
 where W.link_id in ("1")
 order by W.nr_in_article/La.count_links
 limit 5
```

Only if this returns less than 5 results you have to further execute the query again with a changed where condition.

This however will not bring the runtime down by orders of magnitude, but should help a little. If you need more performance I don't see any other way than a materialized view, which I don't think is available in mysql, but can be simulated using triggers.

Comment: I tried it this way but I wanted to show that the relevance is higher so I used the 1- variant.

Comment: MySQL views are in fact just equivalent to joins with subqueries. Confirmed this recently on MySQL 5.5, so they won't make any difference except for readability.

Comment: Yes, that's why I was talking about *materialized* views. Those are tables generated based on a view that can be indexed, hence the order by could be using the index and be orders of magnitude faster.

Comment: I did understand what you meant, just wanted to add my findings ('in fact' -> 'indeed', I am also from Switzerland :) ).